# C# help!! relogin after session auto logout

Tags: c#, browser, logout

wanted to keep an webpage login. username n password needed for login.
the webpage session will auto logout after 10mins of inactivity.

so was think of is there any code in c# that can detect that can detect that the current have logout due to inactivity and execute the login command??

Thanks :)

Comment: I had created a timer set to count for 10 minutes, so the timer will trigger a command to login the webpage every 10mins. however if the webpage was not logout during the timer triggering time, an error will display. so wanted to have some codings to detect that the session have been logout to trigger the "login" command instead of relying on the timer

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems like desired behavior, you could off course increase the session timeout to say an hour if that would please your user more then 10 mins.if you do this make sure the app pool doesn't enter sleep mode after 20 mins(default behavior which you can manage via iis).
If you actually want to reauthenticate your user you could check in your global.asax(or custom provider if you have one) if your user is logged out and if not try and revalidate him.
To do this you would have to have his username and password in either your site's memory or the users cookie. Note that this last approach is quite unsafe since you'd have to store his password in a cookie, be sure to encode it if you do so.

Your global asax would look something like this btw(not copy pastable, just giving you the idea) :

```
if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["StoredCredentials"]
    Membership.ValidateUser(Cookie.Values["userName"], Cookie.Values["userPassword"])
}
```